# Looking for a proverb/idiom that means dont get lot of people to decide on your personal trival matters

Tags: idiom-requests, phrase-requests, proverb-requests

Looking for a proverb/idiom/saying that means

Don't get lot of outside people/heads to decide on personal and/or trivial matter, all of them will give their free recommendation and finally you who has the ownership out of your modesty will have to listen to one of the dominant suggestion and will end up with a undesirable outcome.

So don't get lot of people involved in decision making.

Comment: Don't get a lot of people involved  in something....

Comment: Don’t sweat the small stuff!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Too many cooks spoil the broth](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/too-many-cooks-spoil-the-broth)**

*said when there are too many people involved in trying to do the same thing, so that the final result will not be good.*

Comment: I think this is close but doesn’t in any way include the fact the matter is trivial/personal aspect.

Comment: @k1eran  it does benefit from the informality and trivial nature of the flavor of cooking and also does not carry any connotations of being coerced or dominated for the point of it ... an accidental byproduct of too many inputs.  While perfect is difficult, the thrust of the variety of ways a term might be construed is important.. if a term is misconstrued you don't want it missing the mark widely and this one is very safe in that regard.

Answer (score 1):

**dance to somebody's tune** [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dance+to+(one%27s)+tune)

> To go along with someone else's views or wishes.

As in:

> Take care when dancing to X, X's, or XYZ tune. You may regret it!

Comment: On a situational basis, this could work, however it does risk an accusation of being manipulated with a faint doubt of possible coercion .  The OP did have a bit of a spin in part of his question that way: "out of your modesty will have to listen to one of the dominant suggestion" and if a person wanted to emphasize that 'pushed into it" aspect, "dance to somebody's tune" is better... yet if it were the inadvertent mess a lot of inputs ... this one falls short.. Without enough context the first guess might be being bullied by a boss than muddled by a group.

Answer (score 1):

While 'too many cooks' got my vote, I'd also suggest **"Designed by Committee"** which is us usually used as an insult. If the 'too many cooks' seemed a bit trite or homespun, this newer spin might be called on.

- Note - this phrase is not nearly so applicable to personal advice without some extra careful context building - yet, if it were your vacation itinerary or some sort of costume for a party perhaps it could also work on a personal thing like that.

Like idioms, for it's point to be made it needs to be used correctly to signal it's idiomatic meaning and the audience needs to be aware of the idiomatic use.

I think american professionals are well acquainted with the term but not sure if it works in wider circles.

> [Design by Committee at the Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_committee)
>
> ***Design by committee* is a disparaging term** for a project that **has many designers involved but no unifying plan** or **vision**.
>
> The term is used to refer to suboptimal traits that such a process may produce as a result of having to compromise between the requirements and viewpoints of the participants, particularly in the presence of poor leadership or poor technical knowledge, such as needless complexity, internal inconsistency, logical flaws, banality, and the lack of a unifying vision. This democratic design process is in contrast to autocratic design, or design by dictator, where the project leader decides on the design. The difference is that in an autocratic style, members of the organizations are not included and the final outcome is the responsibility of the leader.
>
> The term is especially common in technical parlance; it legitimizes the need and general acceptance of a unique systems architect and stresses the need for technical quality over political feasibility.

#### a camel is a horse designed by a committee